# Show average instead of sum in a sunburst chart using highcharter

Tags: r, average, r-highcharter, sunburst-diagram

I am trying to make a sunburst chart using the highcharter package in R. Here's the code:

```
data <- read.csv('Student_CGPA.csv')
out <- data_to_hierarchical(data, c(Semester, Course), CGPA)
hchart(out, type = "sunburst")
```

[image]

As you can see in the image, when I scroll over the chart, it shows the sum of the CGPAs for all students for a course.
Output:

```
structure(list(Student_Id = 1:6, Name = c("James", "John", "Robert", 
"Michael", "William", "Mary"), Gender = c("M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "F"), Stream = c("BTech", "BTech", "BTech", "BTech", "BTech", 
"BTech"), College = c("SRM IST", "SRM IST", "SRM IST", "SRM IST", 
"SRM IST", "SRM IST"), City = c("Chennai", "Chennai", "Chennai", 
"Chennai", "Chennai", "Chennai"), State = c("TN", "TN", "TN", 
"TN", "TN", "TN"), Semester = c("Semester 1", "Semester 1", "Semester 1", 
"Semester 1", "Semester 1", "Semester 1"), Course = c("Course 1", 
"Course 1", "Course 1", "Course 1", "Course 1", "Course 1"), 
    CGPA = c(9.7, 5.4, 6, 5.4, 10, 7.3)), row.names = c(NA, 6L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Instead of the sum, is there any way to show the average of the CGPAs for the courses?

Comment: Please share your data. Do this by doing `dput(data)` and paste the output into the original question.

Comment: Since body is limited to 30000 characters, I could not show all of the data.

Comment: In that case you would need to reduce the data down but it still must be sufficient to show the problem. You could start with `dput(head(data))`.

Comment: Thanks! I've added it into the question